# how can I print list like this output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
try:
    strseta = sys.argv[1]
    lista = [int(x) for x in strseta.split(',')]
    strsetb = sys.argv[2]
    listb = [int(x) for x in strsetb.split(',')]
    print("Set A:" ,  strseta.split(','))
    print("Set B:" ,  strsetb.split(','))
    out3 = []
    for i in listb:
        if i in lista:
            out3.append(i)
            print("Intersection of A and B:", out3.split())
    out4 = list(seta)
    for j in listb:
        if j not in lista:
            out4.append(j)
            print("Union of A and B:", out4.split(','))
    out5 = []
    for k in lista:
        if k not in listb:
            out5.append(k)
            print("Difference of A and B:", out5.split(','))

except:
    print("Your input is invalid!")
```

I need to do without using the set
when I enter 2 sys.argv like python3 3.py 5,14,7,9,15,42 9,4,71,5 and  run this code on cmd need to get this output:

Comment: Get rid of the `except:
    print("Your input is invalid!")`. All that's doing is hiding the actual problem. Get rid of the whole `try`, then run it again to see the actual error.

Comment: How can you split a list? `print("Intersection of A and B:", out3.split())`

Comment: Side note: python has specialised operators for sets.

Comment: I need to do without using the set I mentioned above @TrebuchetMS

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax error in your code.
i.e.

1. List do not have a `split()` function, it is available for strings. So to print a list, just do `print(listABC)`, it will print each element differently.
2. `out4 = list(seta)` should be `out4 = list(lista)`

After these changes, your code will work.

**EDIT**

In order to avoid extra prints of the intermediate result of

> Intersection of A and B:

bring the prints after the loop.

like this:

```
for i in listb:
    if i in lista:
        out3.append(i)
print("Intersection of A and B:", out3)
```

Comment: I changed print statements like print("Intersection of A and B:", out3) but I get output like this [9] and [9, 5] . I want this [’5’, ’9’]

Comment: This can be done by printing each element by loop and adding `['`, `','` and `']` manually.

Comment: ty I do it like this but one more thing now for example my program output is [5, 14, 7, 9, 15, 42, 4, 71]but I need it to be like this (with apostrophes) [’5’, ’14’, ’7’, ’9’, ’15’, ’42’, ’4’, ’71’]

Comment: This can be done in 2 ways, 1. instead of making a list, append the result in a string with ',' and print it using `split(',')`. 2. Print each element individually and add the apostrophes manually.

Comment: how can I do this part  append the result in a string with ',' ? I couldn't figure it out exactly. Can you show me how to do it?